# denying special characters jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I need to validate a textarea using the plugin jQuery Validate, to do that I use a regex and I add a method to the plugin:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var check = false;
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "No special Characters allowed here. Use only upper and lowercase letters (A through Z; a through z), numbers and punctuation marks (. , : ; ? ' ' \" - = ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + / < > { } )"
);
```

Then in the options I add the regex:

```
comments:{
    required: true,
    maxlength: 8000,
    regex: /[^A-Za-z\d\-\=\~\!@#\%&\*\(\)_\+\\\/<>\?\{\}\.\$‘\^\+\"\';:,\s]/
}
```

This "works" in a certain way, it does detect the invalid characters and displays the message, the problem is it only works when the special characters are the only ones in the box, for instance:

```
| `` ° ¬ // This shows the error message but...
test | // This won't show the message
```

So if one allowed character is there then the validation just stops working. Am I missing something?

P.S. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the plugin 'cause I've tested the regex with just javascript and it works well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

rather than testing for the presence of the special characters, test for only presence of valid characters

```
regex: /^[A-Za-z\d=#$%...-]+$/
```

Replace `...` with all the special characters you want to allow.  In the example above, `#`, `$`, `%`, and `-` would be allowed.  Note: you don't have to escape (most) of the characters inside of the `[]`.

If you'd like to allow a `-`, it needs to be the last character otherwise regex tries to parse a range. (e.g., `[a-c]` matches a, b, and c. `[a-c-]` matches a, b, c, and -)

Also, if you'd like to allow a `^`, it cannot be the first character otherwise regex treats this as a sort of `not` operator. (e.g., `[^abc]` matches any character that's not a, b, or c)

---

In your example above, the complete regex might look something like this

```
regex: /^[A-Za-z\s`~!@#$%^&*()+={}|;:'",.<>\/?\\-]+$/
```

Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
  z\s`~!@#$%^&*()+={}|     whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '`',
  ;:'",.<>/?\\-]+          '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&',
                           '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '{', '}', '|',
                           ';', ':', ''', '"', ',', '.', '<', '>',
                           '/', '?', '\\', '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

---

[image: check it out!]

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped me (I've been struggling for days -.-). Just for the record, there was a little mistake in your code, you forgot to escape the slash. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah yes, the `/` should be escape because it matches the delimiter.

Comment: And without whitespace, how will be?

Comment: @SoldierCorp, just remove the `\s`