# Javascript restrict special chracters in a username field

Tags: javascript

I found a premade form on the internet I am integrating into my site. However this registration form allows the use of any character. I am trying to limit it to just A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscores, and spaces.

```
$(function(){

var form    = $('form');
var submit  = $('#submit');
var alert   = $('.alert');



$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
var check = false;
var re = new RegExp(regexp);
return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
},
"No special Characters allowed here. Use only upper and lowercase letters (A through Z; a through z), numbers and punctuation marks (. , : ; ? ' ' \" - = ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + / < > { } )"
);



// validate form
form.validate({
    // validation rules
    rules: {
        // name field (required , minimum length 3)
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 25
        },
        // username field (required , minimum length 3, max 8)
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 8,
            regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
        },
        // password field (required , minimum length 6, max 16)
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 16
        },
        // password2 field must be equal to password field
        password2: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        },
        // email field only required
        email: 'required'
    },
    // submit ajax request
    submitHandler: ajaxSubmit
});

// jQuery ajax submit function
function ajaxSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        // form serialize data
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.val('Sending...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if ( data.status === 'success' ) {
                // if responce status == success redirect to success page
                $(location).attr('href','success.html');
            } else {
                // not success! show error messages
                alert.html(data.status).fadeIn();
                submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e);
            // show error message
            alert.html('Sending request fail').fadeIn();
            submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
};
});
```

This is the javascript code that I am trying to edit. I just am unsure what to add for the username to limit the characters. I have tried searching google but all the answers I found come up with a function which I am unsure how to add into this.

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions (regex), they will do what you want :)

Comment: This looks like you're probably using [this jQuery validation library](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry I am new to JS, Jquery, AJax, etc. But yes I think this is jQuery validation.

Comment: @user3764729: Look at the scripts being included in the page to be sure. But it certainly looks like it is.

Answer (score 0):

check this link [denying special characters jQuery Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171085/denying-special-characters-jquery-validate) and below code for you

```
$.validator.addMethod(
"regex",
function(value, element, regexp) {
    var check = false;
    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
},
"No special Characters allowed here. Use only upper and lowercase letters (A through Z; a through z), numbers and punctuation marks (. , : ; ? ' ' \" - = ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + / < > { } )"
);


username:{
required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 8,
         regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
}
```

Comment: Numeric digits are also allowed :)

Comment: replace  regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$/

Comment: Now thats similar to mine answer! ;)

Comment: am I able to just add "regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/" to the username or do I need the $.validator.addMethod to? I will add the entire .js script to first post.

Comment: Ok, I added that method to the very top of the script. Should I put it just above the username validation part?

Comment: just above form.validate({

Comment: Ok, I have added it and updated my first post with the code as it stands now. I have tried to register with a username such as "d@b!d=-" and it still gets put into the database.

Comment: check this  regex:/^[A-Za-z\d=#$%...-]+$/

Comment: Tried with the username "admin=-@1" and it still went through. Also, I am using Cpanel code editor and it has highlighted some of that code a tan color. /^[A-Za-z\d has been highlighted

Comment: after doing some more testing it appears I have another problem. my validation isn't working properly. I am able to add a name, username, and even password that all consist of 1 letter. Something isn't working right.

Comment: add check with form.valid() in your ajaxSubmit method

Comment: I am unsure how to do that.